# CollapsingToolbarLayout inside Viewpager: toolbar acting strange

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a viewpager with fragments, each fragment should include a Collapsing toolbar + image header.

The layout is fine but i have this strange behaviour of the toolbar, which sometimes ignores the top margin and ends under the system bar. This happens:

- on the first Tab
- after scrolling to tab 3 or more, to any "first
  previus tab"
- it only happens on 1 tab at a time (as far i can see)

Also on the first tab the menu is not inflated, despite OnCreateOptionsMenu being run and not throwing any error.

I reviewed the code several times and made lots of adjustments but, for the sake of me, i cannot find what i am doing wrong!

Adding screenshots and some code. Here is [a Github repository](https://github.com/manolodantonio/Tabbed-Collapsing-Toolbar-model) if you want to run it and see this in action. Thanks for any help!

[image]
[image]

and this happens when scrolling left:
[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.manzo.tabbednavigation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:title="Title"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_scroll_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorAccentWarning"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: try adding `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` for your `toolbar`...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 just tried, no visible changes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a solution so i ended up using a workaround.

I removed fitsSystemWindows="true" from the toolbar and added a marginTop of 24dp, which is System bar height as per [material guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-system-bars), I also included an height of 25dp for previous sdks.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

I am open to any suggestion for a "real" solution